# Why If I upload a picture Spring Boot searches in my computer?

Tags: java, spring, image

I am building a spring boot application in which, at a certain point, the user has to input a file (image, text or whatever he wants) and this file is eventually going to be auto-sent to me by mail. I have used this, in my HTML template, to ask for the output;

```
<div class="custom-file">
 <input type="file" class="custom-file-input"
                        name="6?-BBtn9E@=G8Yua" id="6?-BBtn9E@=G8Yua"> <label
                        class="custom-file-label" for="6?-BBtn9E@=G8Yua">Select file</label>
                </div>
```

As you can see I'm using bootstrap.

In my spring boot controller I'm getting that param this way;

```
@RequestParam(name = "6?-BBtn9E@=G8Yua", required = false) File userFile
```

Then the mail is going to be sent regularly (I've previously tested the mail-sending worked, when I still hadn't this file input issue), hence I'm just going to show you the attaching;

```
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
email.attach(userFile);
email.send();
```

However, when I submit, I get this IOException in the console;

```
java.io.IOException: "/Users/username/Eclipse-Workspace/Website/file.txt" does not exist
```

I've picked up a file called file.txt, and since I'm running this on a mac computer the path is /Users/{myUsername}/{Eclipse-Workspace}/{Spring-Boot-Project/{file-name}.
What I want is that Spring Boot searches out of the project, not just inside of it.

Why is it doing so? Thanks for reading!

Comment: I guess you need to clarify few things. There are special characters in your RequestParam also You can use MultipartFile dto to get File object.

Comment: Sir I have tried your advice, however it requires a cast to  for the method attach() (as it requires a File and not MulitpartFile), and when I try to submit I get a nullpointer exception...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want Spring to look outside the project folder you want: `"file:/Users/username/Eclipse-Workspace/Website/file.txt"`.